# Combined And and Or query in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

```
Select * 
FROM dummytable 
WHERE 
    ( minagegrp >=7 AND minagegrp <= 9)
 OR ( maxagegrp >= 7 AND maxagegrp <= 9 )
 OR (minagegrp <= 7 AND maxagegrp >= 9 )  
ORDER BY apptitle DESC
```

I am actually not able to understand why is this query not returning me result properly.

**Condition** is -: Return  those rows which have **either** of the given **conditions true**.

Please help !!

Comment: The query will return the rows that matches the criteria. You've said that you want all the rows that has either of the given conditions true, and thus referring to the same criteria. As such, nobody here can tell you why you're not getting the results you want because you've effectively said you want the results you're getting. Can you please explain, other than with that SQL, what you want?

Comment: Just to be clear. That SQL *will* return all the rows that have at least one of those conditions true. If that's not what you want, please tell us what you actually want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So many conditions not required. Below itself would solve your issue:

**Condition 1 says:**
   `Min value = 7,8,9`

**Condition 2 says :**
   `Max value = 7,8,9`

**Condition 3 says:**
   `Min <7 or Max > 9`

- From 1 and 3, Min can be anything till 9.
- From 2 and 3, Max can be anything above 7.

So, The below query would help you achieve your result.

```
Select * FROM dummytable
where minagegrp <=9
or maxagegrp >= 7
```

Comment: Let the values be 10 and 20 and I need those rows which have either minagegrp between 10 and 20 OR maxagegrp between 10 and 20 OR min and max value between 10 and 20.

Comment: If the min=10 and max = 20, you will surely get output. But please check if both min and max are having int data types. If text data type, then the result will be false.

Comment: Condition 3 says that min < 7 **AND** max > 9, I'm not sure you can combine these 3 into your simpler expression.

Comment: That expression does not reproduce the expression in the query. If this answers the question, then that means the code in the question is wrong. Example: minagegrp and maxagegrp is 1. Will not match the expression in the question, but will match yours.